# Chrome processes running while Chrome browser is not

Tags: google-chrome

I have just booted up my pc (after a shutdown), did not start any app, here's how the task manager looks like.
[image]

A bunch of chrome processes running while the Chrome browser itself is not running.

My pc is jammed because of this. These processes are spawning like virus.
Any suggestions on how to make is sane?

Comment: By 'spawning' do you mean the number of these processes is continously increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Your PC probably isn't "jammed because of this" - as you can see those aren't using CPU at all, just sitting there and doing nothing.

If you want to get rid of them anyway, right-click Chrome icon in the notification area and uncheck a checkbox in the menu that appears.